# Get menu array from HTML string using PHP DOM document

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, domdocument

I have the following code:

```
$string = '<html><head></head><body><ul id="mainmenu">
  <li id="1"><a href="1"> main menu 1 </a> </li>
  <li id="2"> <a href="2"> main menu 2 </a> </li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="3"> <a href="3"> Sub menu 2 </a> </li>
      <li id="4"> <a href="4"> Sub menu 2.1 </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul></body></html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
```

Now I want an array as output containing href, value and submenu fields with respective values using PHP DOM document.

Something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [href] => 1
            [name] => Main menu 1
            [sub] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [href] => 2
            [name] => main menu 2
            [sub] => Array
                (
                   [0] => Array
                    (
                       [href] => 3
                       [name] => sub menu 2
                       [sub] => Array
                             (
                              )

                    )

                   [1] => Array
                       (
                         [href] => 4
                          [name] => sub main menu 2.1
                         [sub] => Array
                             (

                             )

                   )
                )

        )
)
```

I am able to get all the menu items as main menu and all submenu array as empty. How can I achieve this by parsing HTML string?

Comment: Write a recursive function walking over the dom tree and collecting your array. Take some inspiration form here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#122917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you just have the two levels, this code uses XPath to find the start of each menu and then loops through the `<li>` elements.  It does a similar thing for the sub menus, using the current main menu as the start point and only the contents (using `descendant::` to limit the nodes searched)....

(I've had to alter the HTML as there was an extra `<li>` in `<li id="2"> <a href="2"> main menu 2 </a> </li>`)

```
$string = '<html><head></head><body><ul id="mainmenu">
  <li id="1"><a href="1"> main menu 1 </a> </li>
  <li id="2"> <a href="2"> main menu 2 </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="3"> <a href="3"> Sub menu 2 </a> </li>
      <li id="4"> <a href="4"> Sub menu 2.1 </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul></body></html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$menus = [];

$mainMenus = $xp->query('//ul[@id="mainmenu"]/li');
foreach ( $mainMenus as $menu )  {
    $a = $menu->getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    $newMenu = [ "href" => $a->getAttribute("href"),
        "name" => $a->textContent
    ];

    $subMenus = $xp->query('descendant::ul[@class="sub-menu"]/li', $menu);
    foreach ( $subMenus as $menu1 )  {
        $a = $menu1->getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        $newMenu['sub'][] = [ "href" => $a->getAttribute("href"),
            "name" => $a->textContent
        ];
    }
    $menus[] = $newMenu;
}
```

If you have a list of possible ID's, then you could use the XPath to find any of them..

```
//ul[@id="mainmenu" or @id="menu-main" or @id="menu-menu1"]/li
```

You could build this dynamically from an array if you need to...

```
$menu_ids_arr = array('mainmenu', 'menu-main', 'menu-menu1');
$query = '//ul[';
foreach ( $menu_ids_arr as $id )    {
    $query .= '@id="'.$id.'" or ';
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -4).']/li';
$mainMenus = $xp->query($query);
```

Comment: Now what i am looking is instead of hardcode ul id ( in this case, mainmenu), i have a pre defined array of ids and need to parse only that Ul whose id matches with the ids in the array.

For example - 
$menu_ids_arr = array('mainmenu', 'menu-main', 'menu-menu1');
should parse ul only if its id is one of the above 3 (given in array)

Comment: I've added some more explanation for this.